# How to display four column tabular table as a dashboard?

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I'd like to get four columns to display in dashboard with fields from same object. I know how to achieve this (Four columns) using Matrix and Summary Report Format.

The problem is my client wants to look at Four column's of contacts in a single report (also in a dashboard), these are Account Owner, Account Name, Contact Name and Contact rating which is numeric field. I cannot summarize data i.e cannot use report format other than tabular.

I have a report that shows all these fields in tabular format and need a workaround to show the same on dashboard.

I know this is not something you'd normally show on dashboard. I tried to convince client not to do this, but he says his business needs it.

Please guide me if it is possible to do this.

Comment: Title of your post says dashboard. Your post talks about wanting four columns in a single report. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I am able to show the columns in report i want to show that report in the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking to do isn't currently supported by SF as a dashboard component with 4 columns. If you want to display it on it's own, you could recreate the report as a visualforce page. However, you wouldn't have the ability to "drill down" into the data like you could with a dashboard.

Comment: @shankerPaudel - in addition to the limitation as described by crmprogdev,  the VF dashboard component won't render if the dashboard is emailed

Comment: just learned that you can not use dashboard filters if you add a visualforce component.  so it is a relatively easy solution for displaying row level data but has a high price.  imho ridiculous that you cant simply display tabular data in a dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible on dashboards using the table component. It is limited to 3 columns.

You can use a plain report, but my guess it's not what you want.

An ugly workaround could be to use two different table components side by side using the same filter plus order.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Uwe Heim
Using two table wont be possible beacuse i have only one value column (Numeric)" Account Owner, Account Name, Contact Name and Contact rating with is numeric "

Comment: Yeah, that's another constraint. If you can't use the default dashboards and the client feels a pressing to have it exactly this way, you need to create a dashboard-like vf page. Dashboards have several limitations.

Comment: Thanks Ume, I guesstheir is no workaround till date ??